# How to take MKMapView snapshot in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I am able to take `MKMapView` snapshot in portrait mode, but not in landscape mode. I automatically rotate my `UIView` to landscape using the functions given below. I can see the map-view as rotated to landscape. But, when I take snapshot using `MKMapSnapshotter`, I get an image with map in portrait mode again.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeLeft
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeLeft
}
```

My hunch is it has something to do with setting `MKMapSnapshotOptions` to landscape, but I am not sure how to do that.

```
let mapSnapshotOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
mapSnapshotOptions.region = mapView.region
mapSnapshotOptions.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
mapSnapshotOptions.size = mapView.frame.size
```

I expect that above code should have handled it since map-view is already rotated to landscape, but it does not.

```
mapView.frame.size =  (375.0, 647.0)
```

I observe the same value of mapView frame for both cases: portrait and landscape.

I tried using `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. But to no gain. The below function gets called when snapshot options are already set.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    // heading is updated for delegates only after any transition has ended
    // therefore, snapshot properties are set already by the time program reaches this function
    mapView.camera.heading = newHeading.magneticHeading
    mapView.setCamera(mapView.camera, animated: true)
}
```

Please suggest what more can be done?